# Twitter Bootstrap Modal not working in both tabs

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for both tabs and modals. I have two tabs that use identical code. In the first tab the modals work perfectly, but in the second tab the screen will darken but the modal does not appear.

here is my code for calling the modal (same code used in both tabs) in list.php:

```
<a type="button" href="edit.php?id='.$id.'" data-target="#edit_modal" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
```

here is my modal in list.php

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="edit_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times</button>
    <h3>Edit Testimonials</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is edit.php where the true body of the modal is

```
<div id="edit_modal"> 
  <div class="modal-body">
  <?php echo ($name_error != "") ? $name_error : ""; ?>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Testimonial</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="input-xlarge" name="body" cols=100 rows=5><?php echo $testimonial['body']?></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Author</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="input-xlarge" name="author" cols=100 rows=5><?php echo $testimonial['author']?></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Testimonial" name="submit-form" />
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding your question and I think you're leaving a lot out. But just off of what you gave us - it looks like you have two elements with the same ID which isn't valid and would cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what the problem was. changing from id to class solved my problem. thank you