# Modal popup does not work on page with multiple tabs

Tags: html, popup

**EDIT:**

I got the modal popping up (original problem), but a new issue popped up with the modal when saving. I keep getting an error when clicking "Save".

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: csrftoken is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (modalShortListDescription.js:7)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Here's save.js for the save button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#description_save").click(function() {
    var description = $("#form.description").val();
  var idList = $("#idList").attr("id_list");
    var url = "/.../update-list-description";
    csrftoken();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {description : description, idList: idList},
    }).done(function(response){
        $(".modalDescription").modal("hide");
        $(".editDescription").text(description);
    });
  })
})
```

**(FIXED) Original Problem:**
I have a page with multiple tabs that need to have an editable description. So far I can get the modal to popup on the first tab, but when clicking the link for the modal on a different tab, it won't popup. If I could get help on getting the modal to popup on different tabs that would be great!

The closest I could find was this, but their fix just made my modal not popup at all. [Twitter Bootstrap Modal not working in both tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385555/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-working-in-both-tabs)

Here's list.html:

```
<div class="tab-content col-xs-12">
{% for list in lists %}
    <input type="hidden" id="idList" id_list="{{list.id}}">
    {% if forloop.first and not createTabActive %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="list{{list.id}}">
    {% else %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="list{{list.id}}">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="content col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-horizontal sort-by col-xs-12">
                <h3>Description</h3>
                    {% if list.description %}
                        <a href="#update-list-description" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDescription" id="editDescription">{{list.description}}</a>
                    {% else %}
                        <a href="#update-list-description" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDescription">None</a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% include "layout/popUp/modal-short-list-description.html" %}
                </div>
```

Here is the modal modal-short-list-description.html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDescription" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'update-list-description' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Description</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-body-exper modal-body-value modal-body-t">
          <div class="lineEnterValue lineTeamSize lineTitle">
              <div class="form-group {% if form.description.errors %} has-error{% elif form.is_bound %} has-success{% endif %}">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea name="{{ form.description.html_name }}" class="form-control" id="{{ form.description.id_for_label }}" rows="5" style="margin: 0px; height: 90px; width: 455px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        {% if form.description.errors %}
                        <ul class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 error-list text-danger">
                        {% for error in form.description.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error|escape }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer modal-footer-value">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="description_save">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try showing modal using javascript?

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail Hm, didn't try that, but I got it working with a simple fix. Just added {{list.id}} on the modal call. Thanks!